# What would happen if # of events exceeds 500 on Firebase Analytics?

Tags: firebase-analytics

I have been using Firebase Analytics for my apps and I like it.
Currently I have 300 events set up on one of my apps. 
I learned that the max number of events we can have is 500.

What would happen if # of events exceeds 500 on Firebase Analytics?
Would it just stop logging new event? (501st event)
Or is there any better way to avoid it?

I will appreciate your advice!

Answer (score 4):

Extra events are dropped. A firebase_error event is logged with a firebase_error parameter which indicates the error code. See this [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/errors) for more information.

There's no other way to avoid it, but to manage your event logging implementation properly. Note that event in Google Analytics for Firebase is equivalent to the user's interaction within your app.

I would not suggest to create or log an event with incremental index, prefix or suffix in the name. You may also want to use the event parameter.

For example, you have a login page (with authentication methods of using Facebook, Google or Username/Password) and you'd like to track what is the most commonly used by the users. With this, you could log a custom event with the name of "user_login" and a parameter or login_method. After this, add the parameter in the custom parameter reporting to see the counts.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Yes we are using parameters already and save # of events as much as possible. Still worried about event limit.

I was hoping there might be some way out but your confirmed not 
Thanks anyway!

Comment: Can I remove events that are not relevant anymore and replace with a new events?

Comment: @am5a03 unfortunately, no.

Answer (score 0):

Just for clarification because this confused us and there is no clear documentation on this:

The 500 events limit is per user per day and not per project globally. So events are only dropped after a single user uses more than 500 unique events per day, everyone else will continue to log events.

So if you have more than 500 events thats fine, you dont need to replace them you just need to remove them from your current app from being logged and use new ones, then this user will never use the old events and it does not count towards his 500 event limit.

Comment: How did you understand that from the documentation? It doesn't make sense